# Terraform 0.12 - Produce map/object from nested for loop

Tags: terraform

As a follow up to [Terraform 0.12 nested for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56047306/terraform-0-12-nested-for-loops/57280420#57280420). I am trying to produce an object out of a nested loop but failing miserably :(

How would you go about producing:

```
  Outputs:

  association-list = {
    "policy1" = "user1"
    "policy2" = "user1"
    "policy2" = "user2"
  }
```

From:

```
iam-policy-users-map = {
  "policy1" = [ "user1" ]
  "policy2" = [ "user1", "user2" ]
}
```

I have tried many variations of:

```
variable iam-policy-users-map {
  default = {
    "policy1" = [ "user1" ]
    "policy2" = [ "user1", "user2" ]
  }
}

locals {
  association-map = merge({
    for policy, users in var.iam-policy-users-map : {
      for user in users : {
        policy => user
      }
    }
  })

output association-map {
  value = local.association-map
}
```

with zero success so far. Only managed to get the following depending on the variation:

> Error: Invalid 'for' expression.
> Extra characters after the end of the 'for' expression.

> Error: Missing attribute value.
> Expected an attribute value, introduced by an equals sign ("=").

> Error: Invalid 'for' expression.
> Key expression is required when building an object.

> Error: Missing key/value separator. Expected an equals sign ("=") to
> mark the beginning of the attribute value.

For reference, the following code is however capable of producing a list of maps:

```
variable iam-policy-users-map {
  default = {
    "policy1" = [ "user1" ]
    "policy2" = [ "user1", "user2" ]
  }
}

locals {    
  association-list = flatten([
    for policy, users in var.iam-policy-users-map : [
      for user in users : {
        user   = user
        policy = policy
      }
    ]
  ])
}

output association-list {
  value = local.association-list
}
```

> Outputs:
>
> ```
> association-list = [
>   {
>     "policy" = "policy1"
>     "user" = "user1"
>   },   {
>     "policy" = "policy2"
>     "user" = "user1"
>   },   {
>     "policy" = "policy2"
>     "user" = "user2"
>   }, 
> ]
> ```

Comment: so tell us, what's wrong with the source context?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question @BMW. Are you asking why I am trying to produce this map in the context of its surrounding code?

Comment: I think he is asking what is wrong in the surrounding code, because Terraform 0.12.5 throws completely different errors for the snippets you provided, which means there is more going on here.

Comment: I have updated the code, sorry about that.

Comment: Ok I hacked away at your code for a while and fixed up as many issues as I could. It appears your updated code fixed all the same issues that I found with the exception of `policy1 = ["user1"]` fix. At that point I could not figure out how to proceed given documentation, so this might just not be possible currently.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A partial answer can be found at https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/22263.
Long story short: this was a foolish attempt to begin with, a map cannot contain duplicate keys.

I am however still interested in understanding how a map of maps could be produced from a nested for loop. See second code example above, producing a list of maps.

EDIT: a full answer was given on the github issue linked above.

"This is (obviously) a useless structure, but I wanted to illustrate that it is possible:

```
locals {
  association-list = {
    for policy, users in var.iam-policy-users-map:
      policy => {      // can't have the nested for expression before the key!
        for u in users:
           policy => u...
      }
  }
}

Outputs:

association-list = {
  "policy1" = {
    "policy1" = [
      "user1",
    ]
  }
  "policy2" = {
    "policy2" = [
      "user1",
      "user2",
    ]
  }
}
```

"

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do something like this too. Sharing if these terraform list comprehension ideas help someone else trying to mutate to make a derivative map. (I originally found this and the linked issue above via this error `Invalid 'for' expression: Key expression is not valid when building a tuple.`.

My goal was to have resources in the tfstate to not be a list because those would be hard to do tfstate operations on them `...[0]`, `...[1]` are not clear what resources they are.

I had a variable like this which represented users to create some default folders in some s3 bucket.

```
locals { 
  #really in a tfvars file
  bucket_users = 
    "testuser-abc" = {
        make_extra_dirs = ["this-dir", "that-dir-2"]
    }
}


# Create extra folders for non-standard use cases per their configuration.
locals {
    # This is the easy way to get an array of extra directories to create
    # But, we don't want to create it or the `tfstate list` command shows non-helpful indices.
    # e.g. 
    # aws_s3_bucket_object.loop_user_folders_extra_customized_folders["0"]
    # aws_s3_bucket_object.loop_user_folders_extra_customized_folders["1"]
    # aws_s3_bucket_object.loop_user_folders_extra_customized_folders["2"]
    # So use the below trick
    users_with_extra_dirs_flat = flatten([
        for username, user_data in local.bucket_users : [
            for extra_dir in user_data["make_extra_dirs"]: {
                username = username,
                extra_dir = extra_dir,
                unique_key = format("%s--%s", username, extra_dir)
            }
        ] if length(user_data["make_extra_dirs"]) > 0
    ])

    # This is much easier to reason about as it creates nice `tfstate list` 
    # output in case we need to do any future refactorings.
    # e.g.
    # aws_s3_bucket_object.loop_user_folders_extra_customized_folders["testuser-abc--this-dir"]
    # aws_s3_bucket_object.loop_user_folders_extra_customized_folders["testuser-abc--that-dir-2"]
    users_with_extra_dirs_hash_makes_more_maintainable_tfstate_keys_vs_array = {
        for each in local.users_with_extra_dirs_flat : each.unique_key => { username = each.username, extra_dir = each.extra_dir }
    }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "loop_user_folders_extra_customized_folders" {
    for_each = local.users_with_extra_dirs_hash_makes_more_maintainable_tfstate_keys_vs_array
    # lesser way for_each = {for idx, value in local.users_with_extra_dirs_flat : idx => value }

    bucket = "my-example-bucket"
    acl = "private"
    key = "somepath/${each.value.username}/${each.value.extra_dir}/" # Note this must end in a "/" to make that appear as 'directory'
    source = "/dev/null"
}
```

There are probably several ways to clean this up further, though having an intermediate variable and then transforming that helped some with explaining what is happening, and debugging.