# Terraform merge values in maps into sinlge using key lookup

Tags: terraform, hashicorp

I have a locals block which returns data in list of maps

```
    ids = [
  {
    "d81f6779-031f-4aa6-8e88-3242f65e35c0" = "478da44dc0aa8b0cdce5e7448c9509a5095a0f93"
  },
  {
    "d81f6779-031f-4aa6-8e88-3242f65e35c0" = "131e25de9ffd028fc9dab497f537eecb6d1b0faf"
  },
  {
    "e2e6deb4-8512-4089-b2ec-ef77447dabb7" = "f8ea0d6234a8ee2858a3ae04952c6c974337cf6a"
  },
  {
    "e2e6deb4-8512-4089-b2ec-ef77447dabb7" = "143b826f93e78d5a18ac9276972e80414262755e"
  },
  {
    "e2e6deb4-8512-4089-b2ec-ef77447dabb7" = "e7fe936edcc34c258c35aa19b9c702e553e3b265"
  },
]
```

I am looking for an output like below. any function I can use or have to write some for loops?

```
ids = 
{
    "d81f6779-031f-4aa6-8e88-3242f65e35c0" = ["478da44dc0aa8b0cdce5e7448c9509a5095a0f93", "131e25de9ffd028fc9dab497f537eecb6d1b0faf"],
    "e2e6deb4-8512-4089-b2ec-ef77447dabb7" = ["f8ea0d6234a8ee2858a3ae04952c6c974337cf6a", "143b826f93e78d5a18ac9276972e80414262755e","e7fe936edcc34c258c35aa19b9c702e553e3b265"]
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Terraform 0.12 nested for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56047306/terraform-0-12-nested-for-loops)

Comment: `{
    for k in local.ids : keys(k)[0] => values(k)[0]...
  }`

Comment: @jordanm Why not make your comment to an answer? Its correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

This worked by manipulating local variable with [grouping mode](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/for.html#grouping-results) as described in documentation. I didn't had to write another block.

```
    locals {
  ids = {for vfc in data.vra_fabric_compute.this : vfc.custom_properties.vcUuid => vfc.id... } 
}
```