# For in for in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, loops, terraform, amazon-iam

I'm trying to create two loops inside the `resources` block on a `aws_iam_policy_document` statement.

I do have two lists of strings

```
variable "all_services" {
  description = "List of aws services"
  type        = list(string)
  default = [
       "a4b",
       "access-analyzer",
       "acm",
       "acm-pca",
       "aws-marketplace-management"
  ]
}
```

and

```
variable "all_accounts" {
  description = "List of accounts to block"
  type        = list(string)
  default = [
    "11111111111",
    "22222222222",
    "33333333333"
  ]
}
```

I already got it with one loop to iterate on the accounts list

```
   resources = [for account in local.accounts_to_protect: "arn:aws:ec2::${account}:*"]
```

Which has this output

```
              + Resource  = [
                  + "arn:aws:ec2::11111111111:*",
                  + "arn:aws:ec2::22222222222:*",
                  + "arn:aws:ec2::33333333333:*",
```

But I also try to iterate on the service.
I tried something like this with a `for` inside the `for`

```
resources = [for account in var.all_accounts:[
  for services in var.all_services: ["arn:aws:${services}::${account}:*"]]]
```

It gives me this output

```
    Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on block.account.tf line 60, in data "aws_iam_policy_document" "block_accounts":
  60:     resources = [for account in var.all_accounts:[
  61:           for services in var.all_services: ["arn:aws:${services}::${account}:*"]]]
    |----------------
    | local.accounts_to_protect is list of string with 2 elements
    | var.all_services is list of string with 5 elements

Inappropriate value for attribute "resources": element 0: string required.
```

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56066136/3034558 you have to retype your first list to flatten type.

Comment: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/flatten.html#flattening-nested-structures-for-for_each